# copy values from columns to another worksheet

Tags: vba, copy, runtime-error

I'm trying to write a macro that copies the content of column c from Detail to C on sheet 1.

```
Sub copy()
Worksheets("Detail").Range("C2:C").copy Destination:=Worksheets   ("Sheet1").Range("C2:C")
End Sub
```

I got run time error 1004, application defined or object defined error

I have also tried this

```
Sub OneCell()
    Sheets("Detail").Select
    Range("C2:C").copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("c2:c").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

its the same problem and error line is `Range("C2:C").copy`

Comment: C2:C it is correct range?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have tabs named "Detail" and "Sheet1", then try this:

```
Sub copy()
Worksheets("Detail").Range("C2:C").copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
End Sub
```

Comment: After reading the comment from Ivan.s, I realized that there is no ending row reference in the range you are copying.